# Multiple dynamic forms, e.preventDefault(); not triggering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have a PHP page that is generating multiple forms (checkboxes) that I want to update the database when they are toggled - without reloading the page. I have them with a shared class (prim) and each has an id (primary1, primary2, etc).

`onChange="this.form.submit()"` is not being caught and prevented with

```
$(document).on('submit', '.smart-form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
....
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: does the submit handler get called at all? Also, do the form elements have class `smart-form`

Answer (score 0):

The `submit` event is not sent to the document when calling `form.submit()` directly.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.smart-form').change(function () {
  
  //do some verification
  $.ajax({
    url: 'photoPrimary.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {
      //callback methods go right here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.